# Get the actual ending when testing with .endswith(tuple)

Tags: python

I found a nice question where one can search for multiple endings of a string using: `endswith(tuple)`

[Check if string ends with one of the strings from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351951/check-if-string-ends-with-one-of-the-strings-from-a-list)

My question is, how can I return which value from the tuple is actually found to be the match? and what if I have multiple matches, how can I choose the best match?

for example:

```
str= "ERTYHGFYUUHGFREDFYAAAAAAAAAA"
endings = ('AAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAAA')
str.endswith(endings) ## this will return true for all of values inside the tuple, but how can I get which one matches the best
```

In this case, multiple matches can be found from the tuple, how can I deal with this and return only the best (biggest) match, which in this case should be: `'AAAAAAAAA'` which I want to remove at the end (which can be done with a regular expression or so).

I mean one could do this in a for loop, but maybe there is an easier pythonic way?

Comment: Have you considered a regular expression instead? `A{5,9}+$` would match all those endings too and a match object will tell you what matched.

Comment: It it's always the same letter and you want to remove it, why not `.rstrip('A')`? Note that `str` is a bad name for a string, as it shadows the built-in.

Comment: `endswith(tuple)` is trivially implemented as *loop over tuple, run invidual match on string*, so it's really only for convenience (it's not faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = "ERTYHGFYUUHGFREDFYAAAAAAAAAA"
>>> endings = ['AAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAAA']
>>> max([i for i in endings if s.endswith(i)],key=len)
'AAAAAAAAA'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
str= "ERTYHGFYUUHGFREDFYAAAAAAAAAA"
endings = ['AAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAAA']

print max([i for i in endings if re.findall(i+r"$",str)],key=len)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
len(str) - len(str.rstrip('A'))
```

Answer (score -1):

`str.endswith(tuple)` is (currently) implemented as a simple loop over `tuple`, repeatedly re- running the match, any similarities between the endings are not taken into account.

In the example case, a regular expression should compile into an automaton that essentially runs in linear time:

```
regexp = '(' + '|'.join(
   re.escape(ending) for ending in sorted(endings, key=len, reverse=True
) + ')$'
```

**Edit 1**: As pointed out correctly by Martijn Pieters, Python's re does not return the longest overall match, but for alternates only matches the first matching subexpression:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re:

> When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, **even if it would produce a longer overall match**.

(emphasis mine)

Hence, unfortunately the need for sorting by length.

Note that this makes Python's `re` different from POSIX regular expressions, which match the longest overall match.

Comment: No, a `|` delimited set of options matches the *first*, not the longest. Greediness applies to multipliers, not to `|` groups. You would have to sort the endings in reverse order of length.

Comment: `>>> re.search('AA|AAAAA', 'AAAAA').group(0)` returns `AA`, not `AAAAA`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you point me to where this is specified? Because it makes Python's `re` different from POSIX. I just checked again and `regexec()` clearly finds the longest overall match as specified.

Comment: Okay, found it. `re` [documents it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re). As noted, I consider this quite the gotcha, because it's different from the rest of the world ...

Comment: It is not different. You are confusing the quantifiers (`?`, `*`, `+`, `{m,n}`) which do have greedy and non-greedy behaviour, with alternates (the `|`) symbol. Regex is *eager*, not greedy, there, so first match satisfies. Different engines can make different choices here, Python's is regex-directed. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not think so. In your own reference, the last heading actually states the POSIX requirements, which *requires the longest match be returned* and then complains that this is *inefficient* (which is true). Are you sure you are not generalizing from Python to other engines? Because, as noted, `regexec()` *behaves differently* (and it should).

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to generalise to other engines. There are two choices here, Python picked one. But there are other engines that made the same choice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I feel obliged to re-state that you are totally right wrt to Python`s re, it does indeed did left-right-first-match and is specified to do so. I just did not know that and by default assumed POSIX. So thank you again for pointing that out.

Comment: There is a new regex engine in development for Python core, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex, but it did not switch behaviour here (I tested). Perhaps a feature request for the engine?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, I just decided to suggest this as a low-priority proposal. I'm not to angry if it doesn't happen though, as it looks like short-circuit matching has become the de-facto standard (probably because PCRE).