# How to remove a comma and a period from the end of a string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a paragraph such as this:

> Shank spare ribs ball tip, frankfurter alcatra rump pancetta picanha
>   beef ribs biltong pig venison chicken ham hock. T-bone beef ribs
>   chicken pork jerky tenderloin andouille turducken kevin short ribs.
>   Drumstick bacon short loin, chicken turducken leberkas chuck swine
>   pork belly doner biltong ham hock. Swine hamburger tenderloin meatloaf
>   prosciutto pancetta meatball tongue drumstick ham hock. Meatball
>   bresaola landjaeger doner brisket pork belly pancetta spare ribs
>   corned beef tenderloin bacon fatback pork loin boudin rump kevin
>   andouille beef ham capicola biltong. Pork chop corned beef swine
>   turkey, prosciutto biltong kielbasa short loin ground round cupim
>   shoulder.

And I need to write a code that will find out how many times a certain word is said. I can't figure out how to delete the commas and periods that are next to those words! Here is what I have so far:

```
for line in input_file:
    lines = line.split(' ')
    lines = line.replace('\n', '')
    new_List.append(lines)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string ends with one of the strings from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351951/check-if-string-ends-with-one-of-the-strings-from-a-list)

Comment: or even better, [use Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that may help. First, [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
s = '''Shank spare ribs ball tip, frankfurter alcatra rump ...'''
c = Counter(s.split())
```

Note not passing a parameter to [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split):

> If the optional second argument sep is absent or None, the words are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed).

Next, instead of `Counter`, you could use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) to count each word's occurrences:

```
for word in s.split():
    print word, s.count(word)
```

Another option over `str.split` is a simple [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
for word in re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z-_]+', s):
    print word, s.count(word)
```

Finally, as part of your question exactly, you can use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) to strip characters from the end of strings:

```
s = 'foobar.,'
t = s.rstrip('.,')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just split your string by the occurrences of non word character except those between expression like `-` in "T-bone"  using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import re
from collections import Counter

s = '''Shank spare ribs ball tip, frankfurter alcatra rump pancetta 
       picanha beef ribs biltong pig venison chicken ham hock. 
       T-bone beef ribs chicken pork jerky...
    '''

Counter(re.split(r'(?!<\w)\W(?!\w)|\s+', s))
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yO5dL6/2)</kbd>

But if what you want is remove only commas and period the following will work fine:

```
Counter(re.split(r'[,\s.]', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_dict = {}
for line in input_file:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    line = line.replace(',', '')
    line = line.replace('.', '')
    # now line just has words and spaces
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word in word_dict:
            word_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            word_dict[word] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Counter pretty easily:

```
import string
from collections import Counter

# s = s.lower() # if you don't care about case
chars = set(string.ascii_letters + string.whitespace)
c = Counter(''.join(c for c in s if c in chars).split())
```