# pathlib.Path().glob() and multiple file extension

Tags: python, path

I need to specify multiple file extensions like `pathlib.Path(temp_folder).glob('*.xls', '*.txt'):`

How I can do it?

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need to use `pathlib.Path.glob()`

```
from pathlib import Path
def get_files(extensions):
    all_files = []
    for ext in extensions:
        all_files.extend(Path('.').glob(ext))
    return all_files

files = get_files(('*.txt', '*.py', '*.cfg'))
```

Comment: This will get files directly in the current directory, not in any given directory.

Comment: @Boris it answers the question

Comment: @Boris just change `Path('.')` to `Path(temp_folder)`

Answer (score 30):

A bit late to the party with a couple of single-line suggestions that don't require writing a custom function nor the use of a loop and work on Linux:

pathlib.Path.glob() takes interleaved symbols in brackets. For the case of ".txt" and ".xls" suffixes, one could write

```
files = pathlib.Path('temp_dir').glob('*.[tx][xl][ts]')
```

If you need to search for ".xlsx" as well, just append the wildcard "*" after the last closing bracket.

```
files = pathlib.Path('temp_dir').glob('*.[tx][xl][ts]*')
```

A thing to keep in mind is that the wildcard at the end will be catching not only the "x", but any trailing characters after the last "t" or "s".

Prepending the search pattern with "**/" will do the recursive search as discussed in previous answers.

Comment: A caveat with the one-liner solution is that this will also match files with extensions .txs, .tlt, .tls, .xxs and .xlt.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on OS X, Python 3.10, no matches

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 22.04LTS with Python 3.10. Doesn't work for `Path(my_directory).glob("*.[sql][SQL]")` but interestingly it works with `Path(my_directory).glob("*[sSqQlL]")`.

Comment: But as @RajanPonnappan said: it will also work for things like ".ssl", haha

Comment: @Rajan Ponnappan, Jun 5, 2021 at 23:56: This was somewhat hinted in the second to last sentence in the answer above. Thank you for making it explicit.

Comment: @kerfuffle, Oct 6, 2022 at 15:27: Both of your attempts differ than the suggested solution in the answer.

Comment: @dnt2s Help me out here: How does `Path(my_directory).glob("*.[sql][SQL]")` differ from one of your solutions: `Path('temp_dir').glob('*.[tx][xl][ts]')` looks not a bit different semantically.

Comment: @kerfuffle As a simple test put the files a.sql, a.SQL, a.sS, a.qQ and a.lL in a directory. Run "ls *.[sS][qQ][lL]" in that directory and you will see "a.sql a.SQL" (Note the missing "a.sS a.qQ a.lL"). If you then run "ls *.[sql][SQL]" you will see "a.sS a.qQ a.lL" (Note the missing "a.sql a.SQL"). That's how Path.glob() interprets the different letter combinations in the brackets

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the syntax `**` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) which allows you to recursively collect the nested paths.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re


BASE_DIR = Path('.')
EXTENSIONS = {'.xls', '.txt'}

for path in BASE_DIR.glob(r'**/*'):
    if path.suffix in EXTENSIONS:
        print(path)
```

If you want to express more logic in your search you can also use a regex as follows:

```
pattern_sample = re.compile(r'/(([^/]+/)+)(S(\d+)_\d+).(tif|JPG)')
```

This pattern will look for all images (tif and JPG) that match `S327_008(_flipped)?.tif` in my case. Specifically it will collect the sample id and the file name.

Collecting into a set prevents storing duplicates, I found it sometimes useful if you insert more logic and want to ignore different versions of the files (`_flipped`)

```
matched_images = set()

for item in BASE_DIR.glob(r'**/*'):
    match = re.match(pattern=pattern_sample, string=str(item))
    if match:
        # retrieve the groups of interest
        filename, sample_id = match.group(3, 4)
        matched_images.add((filename, int(sample_id)))
```

Comment: I like this one better since you only have to walk the directory tree once instead of n * len(extensions). Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the following folder structure is prepared.

```
folder
├── test1.png
├── test1.txt
├── test1.xls
├── test2.png
├── test2.txt
└── test2.xls
```

The simple answer using `pathlib.Path` is as follows.

```py
from pathlib import Path

ext = ['.txt', '.xls']
folder = Path('./folder')

# Get a list of pathlib.PosixPath
path_list = sorted(filter(lambda path: path.suffix in ext, folder.glob('*')))
print(path_list)
# [PosixPath('folder/test1.txt'), PosixPath('folder/test1.xls'), PosixPath('folder/test2.txt'), PosixPath('folder/test2.xls')]
```

If you want to get the path as a list of strings, you can convert it to a string by using `.as_posix()`.

```py
# Get a list of string paths
path_list = sorted([path.as_posix() for path in filter(lambda path: path.suffix in ext, folder.glob('*'))])
print(path_list)
# ['folder/test1.txt', 'folder/test1.xls', 'folder/test2.txt', 'folder/test2.xls']
```

Answer (score 1):

A four-liner solution based on [Check if string ends with one of the strings from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351977/6293886):

```
folder = '.'
suffixes = ('xls', 'txt')
filter_function = lambda x: x.endswith(suffixes)
list(filter(filter_function, glob(os.path.join(folder, '*'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution:

```
from pathlib import Path
suffixes = ["html","htm","htmx","js","svg","php"]
paths = [path for i in suffixes for path in Path('.').glob("*."+i)]
```

It is easier to add and remove suffixes from the list than to create new patterns.

Patterns like: `'*.[tx][xl][ts]'` have several drawbacks, they might return also combinations of the characters and also did not work on my MacOS 10.15 with Python. 3.8.

Often I use `rglob` instead of `glob` for accessing the subfolders.