# Converting a Trie into JSON format

Tags: python, json, trie

I'm planning to implement autocomplete feature using trie data structure. I want to convert my trie into a JSON format.

```
class Trie(object):
"""Class representing the structure of trie"""
   def __init__(self):
      self.children={}     #Links to other nodes
      self.isEndOfWord=False
```

This is the output of my trie program

```
[
    ('Z', <search_trie.Trie object at 0x7f3350f32c50>),
    ('j', <search_trie.Trie object at 0x7f3353e77da0>),
    ('z', <search_trie.Trie object at 0x7f3350f32be0>),
    ('M', <search_trie.Trie object at 0x7f33538eb668>)
]
```

where:

```
'Z'-character stored in the trie node

<search_trie.Trie object at 0x7f3350f32c50> -points to other node
```

How can I convert this to JSON format? I don't want the object address to be present in JSON. How can I extract the nodes from the address  and include it in JSON?

EDIT:
This is my code. What modification should I do to avoid storing nodes as references? If I can store the actual object value instead of address, converting it into JSON will be simple.

```
from functools import reduce
class Trie(object):
    """Class representing the trie"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.children={}
        self.isEndOfWord=False

    def add(self,char):  #Adds a character to dictionary and creates a new node 
        self.children[char]=Trie()

    def insert(self,word): #Insert a new word to the trie
        node=self
        for char in word:
            if char not in node.children:
                node.add(char)
            node=node.children[char]
        node.isEndOfWord=True

    def search(self, word): #Search for a particular word in a trie
        node = self
        for char in word:
            if char not in node.children:
                return False
            node = node.children[char]
        return node.isEndOfWord

    def all_suffixes(self,prefix):
        results = set()
        if self.isEndOfWord:
            results.add(prefix)
        if not self.children: 
            return results
        return reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, [node.all_suffixes(prefix + char) for (char, node) in self.children.items()]) | results

    def autocomplete(self, prefix):
        node = self
        for char in prefix:
            if char not in node.children:
                return set()
            node = node.children[char]
        return list(node.all_suffixes(prefix))
```

Comment: Do you mean how can you change the default object representation to look like JSON? For that you can override the `__repr__` method.

Comment: You can represent a trie with a standard dictionary ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296069/6779307)), then you can use `json.dump` to convert it to a json file.

Comment: Would agree to use a dictionary to represent the trie. Otherwise, you need to specify a way to represent it (e.g., an id or hash)