# Finding if a word ends with a certain suffix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've trying to make it work without if statement with python in which it does work most of time until it reaches a word like 'celebration'. I'm not understanding what's causing this to happen.

```
common_suffix = ['ly', 'ion', 'ed', 'able']
def ends_in_common_suffix(word):
    for suffix in common_suffix:
        last_word = word[-len(suffix)]
        return last_word < suffix
```

Comment: Also [Check if string ends with one of the strings from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351951/check-if-string-ends-with-one-of-the-strings-from-a-list)

Comment: How can it ever consider the second suffix?

Comment: Sorry, if this sounds like a stupid question, but why wouldn't it consider the second suffix?

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop. Consider `any(word.endswith(suffix) for suffix in common_suffix)` if you only need to know if a words ends thus, or move the return out of the loop (not sure if that's the only problem).

Comment: word[-len(suffix)] will grab the letter at the `-index` of the length, so for instance 'ly' is len 2, so if my word was 'suffix' the line `last_word = word[-len(suffix)]` would set `last_word` to 'i' (second to last letter).

To make this work you can do something like 
    
    `def ends_in_common_suffix(word):
      matches = [word.endswith(suffix) for suffix in common_suffix]
      return any(matches)`

Comment: Thank you for all the support! The code finally worked.