# Check which ending a string has from a list

Tags: python

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351951/check-if-string-ends-with-one-of-the-strings-from-a-list) I can find if a string has a certain ending from a list:

```
>>> 'test.mp3'.endswith(('.mp3', '.avi'))
True
```

Is there a way to extend it to find which specific ending it has? e.g, the index of the
ending from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as straight forward as the sentence that you speak out loud when talking to someone. Even most keywords are included:

> `for` each ending `in` list of endings`:` check `if` ending is present: then stop.

```
for ending in [".mp3", ".avi"]:
    if "test.mp3".endswith(ending):
        print(ending)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to iterate on the different possible `ends`,

- raise a `StopIteration` if no `end` matches

  ```
  ends = ('.mp3', '.avi')
  first_end = next(end for end in ends if 'test.mp3'.endswith(end))
  print(first_end) # .mp3
  ```
- return `None` if no `end` matches

  ```
  ends = ('.mp4', '.avi')
  first_end = next((end for end in ends if 'test.mp3'.endswith(end)), None)
  print(first_end)  # None
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension to parse all possible matches, and then take the first (and the only) match with a ternary `if` condition operator.

```py
endings = (".mp3", ".avi")
match = [ending for ending in endings if "test.mp3".endswith(ending)]
match = match[0] if match else None
```