# How do I count amount of item with same text in a listbox (Tkinter)

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to get the number of items with the same text at the end like a,1 b,1 and c,1.

I cant think of anything to make it work.

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Listbox(root).pack()
Listbox.insert(END,'a,1','b,1','c,1')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide sample input and output so that we can better understand what you want to do, as it is currently I don't think anyone has a clear understanding of your goals

Comment: Are you aware of `string.endswith()`? [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351977)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, `listbox.get(0, END)` (which gets all the items in a `Listbox`), and `str.endswith()` to count the number of items that end with a certain string. Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
list_box = Listbox(root)
list_box.pack()
list_box.insert(END,'a,1','b,1','c,1')

# Count the number of items that end in "a,1"
items = 0
for i in list_box.get(0, END):
    if i.endswith("a,1"):
        items += 1

print("{} items end with 'a,1'.".format(items))

root.mainloop()
```